# GPS tracking within vehicle in android

Tags: android, gps

I am in need to develop an android app where the device will track the distance traveled while the user is in a moving vehicle. I am getting the GPS values at small interval so that I can retrieve the distance and sum them up. But the problem I am facing is, while the user is in the vehicle, the device is not getting a clear view of the sky. Hence, the GPS device cannot get values as frequently as I desire. Thus, the result produced contains huge fluctuations. I tried using the network provider, but that is even worse in this scenario.

It would be very much helpful if anyone can suggest me a solution to this problem.

Comment: I think the issue maybe with either your device or location.

Comment: Short of putting a GPS receiver on the outside of the car - you won't do any better. Consider if the user drives in a tunnel - no GPS signal there. If you are wondering how other vendors stay on the road due to GPS position variation, well they fudge what the user sees to keep it on the road - i.e. I know the user is in motion so if location is 3 m off the road put the symbol on the road.

Comment: About the device or location issue, I don't know if the location is pin-point accurate here in Bangladesh. The accuracy here works for me. I tried the app under open sky and the readings were quite frequent. But under a roof, the device took quite some time for each consecutive update.

Comment: Morrison Chang, a rough estimation may be the only way I can go with at the moment. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

Just put the receiver onto the inner side of the windshield, like all navigation systems do. This should give an acuracy of about 3-6m. (when SBAS correction is available in your location) or up to 10m if not. 
If the receiver is not state of the art (combined GPS + GLONASS or BEIDOU) then you will have problem in cities, especially in urban canyons with location jumps up to 30m.
This is normal. To get correct result for a GPS application within a city you need advanced algorithms. Just summing up the distance between two consecutive locations is to primitive, this never works well. Distance calculation by GPS has be answered some times her at SO. Use the search engine, to get more info at that topic.

Of course, set the device to GPS provider only, with maximum precision.